# Un-escape unicode strings, can't replace '%' with '\u'

Tags: qt4

I would like to un-escape unicode strings like `%uXXXX%uYYYY`, so I tried:

```
QString unescapeUnicode (const QString & src)
{
    return QString::fromUtf8 ( src.replace ("%", "\u").toAscii() );
}
```

Since `\u` wasn't a standard escape sequence, it won't compile,

but output with `QString::fromUtf8 ("\uXXXX\uYYYY")` works perfectly, what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping that works with literal strings does not work with strings. You need to parse the unicode value of each character and build the string character by character. For example like this:

```
QString unescapeUnicode(const QString& src)
{
    QStringList chars = src.split("%u", QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    QChar* qchars = new QChar[chars.size()];

    bool ok;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i)
    {
        qchars[i] = QChar(chars[i].toInt(&ok, 16));
        if (!ok)
            return "ERROR";
    }

    QString result(qchars, chars.size());
    delete[] qchars;
    return result;
}
```

And usage:

```
QString txt = unescapeUnicode("%u00a2%u20ac%u3b2");
```